# Show that the stabilizer $G_Y$ is closed under multiplication.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider an action of a group $G$ on a set $X$ and let $ Y \subseteq X$.

Show that $G_Y$ is closed under multiplication.

So I have approached this by taking 2 elements in the stabilizer.

$g_1$$y$$g_2$$y$ and I say that this is equal to  $g_1$$y$$y$ by the axiom set by the stabilizer ($gy=y$) and then I know that $y$$y$ must be in $Y$ by the axioms of a subgroup.

Does this argument suffice?

The definition of a stabilizer: $G_Y := \{g \in G \mid gy=y, \text{ for all } y \in Y\}$.

Comment: What is the stabiliser of G ? Some people are not familiar with the term stabiliser, so if you give the definition of it, it would be much better.

Comment: @Leth Added, sorry. I hope you know what I mean

Comment: So what is the difference between a unit element and a stabilizer?

Comment: This is groups, some groups don't have units but have stabilisers

Answer (score 1):

You need to show that for all $g_1,g_2 \in G_Y$, $g_1g_2 \in G_Y$ as well. And to do so, you need to show that for all $y \in Y$, $g_1g_2y = y$. Since $g_1 \in G_Y$ you have $g_1y = y$ for all $y \in Y$. Similarly for $g_2$. Hence $$(g_1g_2)y = g_1(g_2y) = g_1y = y$$

Comment: Yeah this is what I meant, but I don't know why I put 2 y's, thanks though